# How to open console in firefox python selenium?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, firefox-developer-tools

Im trying to open firefox console through Selenium with Python. How can I open firefox console with python selenium? Is it possible to send keys to the driver or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to simulate the same procedure as a "regular" firefox window using the `send_keys` function:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'k')
```

Comment: That works aswell, and that will work if you got firebug installed.

Comment: Even better: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'k')

Comment: In general it is a good practice to use the WebDriver waits, I always set the implicit wait so I don't have to use explicit waits for each element as you have pointed out. After create the driver element add: `driver.implicitly_wait(15)`

Comment: above solution is no more working for - VS 2017 , Selenium v 3.12.1 ,C# , Firefox V 60.0.2 , Chrome V 66 , Nunit v3.10.1 , Gecko Driver v 20.1 , chrome driver v 2.4

Answer (score 7):

I know this is relatively old but I ran into this issue recently.  I got firefox to automatically open devtools by passing in a browser process argument "-devtools".

Selenium: 3.14
geckodriver: 0.21.0
firefox: 61.0.1

```
  from __future__ import print_function

  from datetime import datetime
  import logging
  import os

  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

  def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    logging.info("RUNNING: " + scenario.name)
    print("Browser Test starting.\n")

    options = FirefoxOptions()
    options.log.level = "trace"
    options.add_argument("-devtools")

    if 'headless' in os.environ and os.environ['headless'] == '1':
         options.headless = True

    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)


    context.driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Here is a list of all of the possible command line arguments for FireFox.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: `webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)` -> `webdriver.Firefox(options=options)`.

Comment: What are the values of the context and scenario objects that need to be passed into as arguments to call the function above?  Can someone please provide a usage example...

Answer (score 2):

I have no firebug installed, this works on Macos:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.ALT + 'k')
```

Comment: Command + alt + k / Ctrl + shift + k will always work. The thing is if firebug is installed it replaces the F12 button to open firebug, and not the developer tools.

Comment: above solution is no more working for - VS 2017 , Selenium v 3.12.1 ,C# , Firefox V 60.0.2 , Chrome V 66 , Nunit v3.10.1 , Gecko Driver v 20.1 , chrome driver v 2.4

Comment: @MikeASP what works then for the versions you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.F12).key_up(Keys.F12).perform()

Without firebug installed at least :)

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 60+ you need to use the chrome context (CONTEXT_CHROME) and select some UI element to send keys to the console, this example shows you how to use a GCLI command from console using chrome context and tabbrowser-tabs UI element to issue the keystrokes

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

profile = FirefoxProfile()
# Allow autoplay
profile.set_preference("media.autoplay.default", 0)
cap = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
options = Options()
options.headless = True
webdriver = Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, capabilities=cap, options=options)
webdriver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzKkl64rRbM")
try:
    time.sleep(3)
    with webdriver.context(webdriver.CONTEXT_CHROME):
        console = webdriver.find_element(By.ID, "tabbrowser-tabs")
        console.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + Keys.LEFT_SHIFT + 'k')
        time.sleep(5)
        console.send_keys(':screenshot --full-page' + Keys.ENTER)
        console.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + Keys.LEFT_SHIFT + 'k')
except:
    pass
webdriver.quit()
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the developer tools in `Firefox==103.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Developer console on Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        options = driver_options,
        executable_path = "c:\webdrivers\geckodriver.exe")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.ALT + 'k')
```

Comment: after running this in python on windows 10 I get error, Traceback (most recent call last): File XXX, line 5, in driver_options = Options() NameError: name 'Options' is not defined