# Is the Firefox Web Console accessible in headless mode?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox

The title says it all: I am wondering whether it is possible to interact with the Firefox [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) upon starting Firefox in [headless mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode).

More generally, I'd settle for some way of accessing it programmatically, in scripts.

**What I've tried:**

So far I've been playing with the [Javascript bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) to [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ) without success:

Starting Firefox with the [-devtools option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) from Selenium does opn the dev tools, but I then [cannot](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8665) send key combinations that will switch me to the actual console, or in fact interact from my `.js` script with the open devtools window in any way.

---

**Edit**

In response to the first comment below: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33547261/11064961) does not seem to help. The console is not opened when I send `CTRL+SHIFT+k` to the `body` tag of `google.com`:

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var inpt = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/input');

var options = new firefox.Options();

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

(async function(){
    await driver.get('https://google.com');
    var bdy = await driver.findElement(By.id('gsr'));
    await bdy.sendKeys(inpt.Key.CONTROL + inpt.Key.SHIFT + 'k');    
})();
```

This opens the page (`google.com`) and returns no errors, but there's no console anywhere.

For good measure: sending just `inpt.Key.SHIFT + 'k'` *does* enter a capital 'K' in the Google search field, so I know the keys are referenced correctly.

Also, sending just `'k'` enters a small 'k' in the search field. It's only the three-key combo that does not work.

**2nd edit:**

I take it back: the [newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376203/11064961) does work, precisely as-is (I switched to [Python](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-webdriver/) from `node`).

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33547261/12870513

Comment: @Karthik: not so much.. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I take that back: it did work, thanks! See the 2nd edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment below by [Karthik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12870513/karthik) does resolve the matter, but I would like to summarize here and document working solutions that automate Firefox-Web-Console access.

The point of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546911/how-to-open-console-in-firefox-python-selenium/59376203#59376203) I linked to above (in my 2nd edit) is that in order to have full access to the Firefox browser key controls one must

- first switch Firefox [context](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox_exports_Context.html) to `chrome` (from the default `content` context)
- direct the automated browser driver to locate the element carrying id `tabbrowser-tabs`
- send the key combo (in this case `Ctrl+Shift+k`) to that element.

---

### Concrete working solutions:

#### [Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

The script is

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

options = Options()
webdriver = Firefox(options=options)
webdriver.get("https://google.com")
try:
    time.sleep(3)
    with webdriver.context(webdriver.CONTEXT_CHROME):
        console = webdriver.find_element(By.ID, "tabbrowser-tabs")
        console.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + Keys.LEFT_SHIFT + 'k')
                
except:
    pass
```

Run with `python <path-to-script>` it opens a Firefox window displaying `google.com` and the console at the bottom.

#### [Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

Here the full script is

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var inpt = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/input');

var options = new firefox.Options();

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

(async function(){
    await driver.get('https://google.com');
    await driver.setContext("chrome");

    var tabs = await driver.findElement(By.id('tabbrowser-tabs'));
    await tabs.sendKeys(inpt.Key.CONTROL + inpt.Key.SHIFT + 'k');
    
})();
```

Run with `node <path-to-script>` it achieves the same effect as above: a Firefox window open on `google.com`, with the console open at the bottom.